# Gradle trying to unzip a pom typed dependency

Tags: gradle, zip, pom.xml, mtj, netlib

In a project of mine I have a dependency on a java matrix library MTJ which I specify like this in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java:mtj:1.0.4'
  ...
}
```

MTJ in turns depends on netlib, more concretely it would be the equivalent of explicitly adding compile `'com.github.fommil.netlib:all:1.1.2'` above.

When I run the gradle build. I get the following error:

```
Could not expand ZIP '/Users/valentin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fommil.netlib/all/1.1.2/f235011206ac009adad2d6607f222649aba5ca9e/all-1.1.2.pom'. 
archive is not a ZIP archive.
```

So somehow gradle is confused and treats the file as been a zip file when it is just a pom that points to other dependencies.

Anyone has a fix or knows of a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.fommil.netlib%7Call%7C1.1.2%7Cpom). The dependency you specified is of type `pom` - this type in maven is used to aggregate projects. Gradle downloads it, tries to unzip and fails. It seems that this is not what you're looking for. 
[Here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.fommil.netlib) you can find other artifacts for group: `com.github.fommil.netlib`. Please find a jar you're looking for and specify the dependency directly.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that I don't import netlib directly but indirectly via mtj... do you think this is a bug in mtj dependencies definition or a limitation/bug in gradle?

Comment: Is there a way I can include dependencies in gradle without triggering recursive dependency inclusion?

Comment: You can exclude a single dependency or a group of them. Then add the netlib dependency separately. Have a look at this section: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies

Comment: Yup I've just noticed that ```transitive = true|false```. That might just be enough. Thanks a lot.