# Make jar with pom dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I want to make an executable jar in Gradle:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
           attributes (     
                'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.json_validator.Main'
            )
    }
    baseName 'json-validator'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

But i have an error from Gradle "Could not expand ZIP ..... archive is not a ZIP archive". I have this error on dependency, which is not .jar, it is pom.

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey', name: 'jersey-bom', version: '2.17', ext: 'pom'
```

How can i make an executable jar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the same issue described here: [Gradle trying to unzip a pom typed dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361545/gradle-trying-to-unzip-a-pom-typed-dependency)

The answer there describes what is happening and a possible remedy.

Alternatively, it should execute if you remove `, ext: 'pom'` from your dependency though I don't know if this is what you are going for.